# How can I run WSO2-CEP or WSO2-BAM and WSO2-BPS at the same machine at the same time?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I am working on event processing and business activity monitoring in SOA. I want to run WSO2-CEP and/or WSO2-BAM while WSO2-BPS is running. But the problem is that when I run WSO2-BPS to run my business processes, I can't run WSO2-CEP and/or WSO2-BAM and can't access their Management Consoles.
Please help me. Thanks!

---

Thanks a lot for your quick response, Maninda. 
Actually, I don't want to monitor the Rules engine. 
What I want to do is to monitor a BPEL process (Service Composition layer) and the underlying service infrastructure (like tomcat, the web services themselves, the BPEL engine, etc.) which we can call them Service Infrastructure layer, and analyse the KPIs (using the BAM) and the process metrics (using the CEP), find the correlation between the KPIs and the metrics, and try to adapt the business process (in this case BPEL) pro-actively or re-actively, in accordance to the governing business rules (using the Rules Esngine).
Do you have any sample which cover all of them or at least most of them? Or any other idea? 
Thanks in advance for your time and attention.

---

I want to monitor a BPEL process and doing some BAM, Rules processing and CEP on the running BPEL process and adapt it if required. Is there any case study or sample which covers BPEL, BAM, CEP and Rules Engine? What should I do? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That is because all the servers are using the same port numbers for similar things. You can simply offset the port number of other servers in different offsets to set different port numbers. It will increment all the port numbers used in the server by the port offset.

e.g.:

In WSO2BAM do not change port offset (default port offset is 0), in WSO2BPS set port offset as 1 and in WSO2CEP set port offset as 2.

In order to change the port offset go to, [wso2-server-home-location]/repository/conf/carbon.xml file and change the `<Offset>0</Offset>` as required.

Comment: Thanks Maninda. I managed to run the 3 of them at the same time. Good progress! However, it makes my machine to suffer bad performance downgrade. What I want to do is to monitor a BPEL process and doing some BAM, Rules processing and CEP on the running BPEL process and adapt it if required. Is there any case study or sample which covers BPEL, BAM, Rules Engine and CEP? What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/Data+Agents you can find all the Data Agents supported by BAM 2.2.0. Some of them are compatible with CEP as well. (e.g. BAM Mediator) I have heard that there was a BPS monitoring agent was developing for BAM but could not find. If I could find I will let you know. I am not aware how to monitor Rules engine with BAM. Most probably that kind of Agent may not already available. But using the JMX Agent perhaps you will be able to monitor it as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Maninda. Could you please read my comments bellow, because it was longer that the comments limitations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For BAM JMX Agent will be helpful for these scenarios. Find how to use it in [this document](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/Setting+Up+JMX+Agent+for+BAM). This is a very new feature and I haven't tried this before. Hope this will help you to pump monitored events to BAM in other WSO2 products if the JMX Agent could be successfully installed in theses products. No other sample is available as I believe as this is a very new feature.